# Unable to print XML from webservice

Tags: php, xml, web-services

I need to make a webservice call to target website and parse the xml response returned by it.

API :

```
http://targetwebsite/feed/product/tablets.xml?user=name&key=key
```

I am trying to print the xml first(transformation once printed) from the php code as follows

```
<?php
    $url = file_get_contents('http://targetwebsite/feed/product/tablets.xml?user=name&key=key');
    $xml = new SimpleXmlElement($url);
    print_r($xml);
?>
```

But unfortunately I don't see any xml response when I access my php file.

Comment: Do you get any response from `echo $url`? Maybe the XML from the webservice is broken.

Comment: just make sure your url along with your credentials (key and username) are correct as you are the only one who can reproduce this problem

Comment: @Ghost Thanks for reply. If i copy paste the url in the browser(chrome) i am getting the output for the same credentials.So 100% sure that credentials is not the problem

Comment: @user2603466 also, consider the possibility that the xml is broken/malformed just as dave said above. try to turn on error reporting to check for notices.

Comment: @DaveChen  I update the code as follows now <?php
 $url = file_get_contents('http://targetwebsite/feed/product/tablets.xml?user=name&key=key');
 echo $url;
 echo "hello"
?>
I can see only hello in the web page nothing else

Comment: Can you view-source? When the XML is echoed out, you won't be able to see anything because the browser is parsing it as HTML. Either that, or the webservice is truly not returning anything.

Comment: @DaveChen : When I view source also, i see nothing related to the XML response.  If web service is not returning any thing how can i see the response if i copy paste the $url value in the google chrome?  Can u please let me know.  If that works it should work here also right

Comment: Can you show us the API link you're using? It's possible you need to provide more information to the API for it to be accepted. If you paste the same URL into your browser, do get a response?

Comment: @DaveChen : Yes I am getting response when i paste the same link in the browser.  My API Link : 'http://api.pricecheckindia.com/feed/product/mobile_phones/Samsung+S4+I9500.xml?user=saibrpwx&key=HGYMDNVKJGSPFQCP'

Comment: @user2603466 I can get a response using this url and your code. Are you sure `file_get_contents` works properly? You might need to enable, `allow_url_open` in php.ini. [Check this](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're really using the correct url. It works just as fine:

```
$url = 'http://api.pricecheckindia.com/feed/product/mobile_phones/Samsung%20S4%20I9500.xml?user=saibrpwx&key=HGYMDNVKJGSPFQCP';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
```

[It works here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tSf8bf)

Sidenote: To get useful information, try to turn on error reporting and put this on top of your PHP file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Supplemental info: As @Dave said in the comments, it might be worth looking on the ini settings about `allow_url_fopen` as you cannot make that request without it being open/turned on.

Comment: I'm thinking the OP is running the code on a shared server where the settings lock file_get_contents, cURL, etc. But you're right, other than those factors, his code is fine.

Comment: @DaveChen oh yeah, excellent point. shared server might have it disabled it and might be the main issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  This is my updated code now <?php
    $url = 'http://api.pricecheckindia.com/feed/product/mobile_phones/Samsung%20S4%20I9500.xml?user=saibrpwx&key=HGYMDNVKJGSPFQCP';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($xml); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?> No response in the web pagem but when i view source i can see <pre>.

Comment: @DaveChen Let me check with my hosting provider.  And update you the same

Comment: @ All allow_url_fopen is set to  Off. php version is 5.3 Do i need to change this?

Comment: @user2603466 yes, most definitely, you need to turn it to `On`

Comment: Got it Now Excellent.  Thanks Dave and Ghost for your time and support

Comment: @user2603466 sure man, im glad we were able to help. biggest credit to Dave. he's the one who figured it out.